# sending parameter from controller to view

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, parameters, hyperlink

Is there any way to send data from controller to view.
what I am doing is that user has the option of links and according to links user clicks the corresponding data is passed to the controller and another view is loaded from controller corresponding to that link.
But I dont know how to do that.
I am using bonfire 
here is my controller code :-

```
function my_tickets() {
        $username = $this->auth->username();
        $this->load->model('helpdesk_model');
        $result_set = $this->helpdesk_model->my_tickets($username);
        foreach($result_set->result()  as $data ) {
            $title[] = $data->title;
            $category[]=$data->category;
            $priority[]=$data->priority;
            $date[]=$data->date;
            $post_status[]=$data->post_status;
            $userfile_path[] = $data->userfile_path;
        }
        $arraysize=count($title);
        Template::set('arraysize',$arraysize);
        Template::set('title',$title);
        Template::set('category',$category);
        Template::set('priority',$priority);
        Template::set('date',$date);
        Template::set('post_status',$post_status);
        Template::set('username',$this->auth->username());
        Template::set('userfile_path',$userfile_path);
        Template::render();
    }
    function full_post(){
        Template::render();
    }
    }
```

In my model part :-

```
function my_tickets($username){
        $this->db->select('title,userfile_path,category,priority,date,post_status');
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $result = $this->db->get('tbl_tickets');
        return $result;
        }
```

My views are :-

```
<?php 
$arraysize =Template::get('arraysize');
$title[] = Template::get('title');
$category[]=Template::set('category');
$priority[]=Template::set('priority');
$date[]=Template::set('date');
$post_status[]=Template::set('post_status');
$username = Template::set('username');
$userfile_path = Template::set('userfile_path');
?>
<h3>Total Number Of posts :&nbsp; <?php echo $arraysize; ?> </h3>
<h2>Your Posts</h2>
<?php echo "serail. title | category | priority | date of starting post | post status "; ?> 
<?php 
    for ($i=0; $i <$arraysize; $i++) { 
    ?>
    <p> <?php echo ($i+1).". ".$title[$i]." | ".$category[$i]." | ".$priority[$i]." | ".$date[$i]." | ".$post_status[$i]; 
            echo "<a href=\"/helpdesk/full_post\">Click to see </a>";
        ?>
    </p>
    <?php
   } 
   ?>
```

In my full_post controller function I want the parameter which the user clicks in the link `click to see`.
helpdesk is my controller name.
helpdesk_model is my model name. and 
my_tickets is my view name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing this with the help of form using hidden fields:-
I have slightly change my view page like this :-

```
for ($i=0; $i <$arraysize; $i++) { 
    echo "<p>".($i+1).". ".$title[$i]." | ".$category[$i]." | ".$priority[$i]." | ".$date[$i]." | ".$post_status[$i]."</p>";
    echo form_open('/helpdesk/full_post');
    echo form_hidden('path',$userfile_path[$i]);
    echo form_submit('submit', 'click to see');
    echo form_close();
   }
```

and In controller page I am doing :-

```
function full_post(){
        Template::set('path',$this->input->post('path'));
        Template::render();
        }
```

this is the thing I need, is this good way to do it..?
Is there any other better idea to do it..?

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller function with parameter and provide the links with parameter in it.

```
echo anchor('controller/functionName/parameter','display text');

function functionName($parameter ='')
{
    //Do something with the parameter here when user click on the displayed text.
}
```

I am not sure, if this is you want, because this is very easy thing.

Comment: No I don't want this. I want to send some value from view to controller that value is the link clicked by user..
suppose in my view I have 3 links a,b,and c, if user clicks a then controller function will be called and the value corresponding to a will be passed from view to that function

Comment: yes that can be done using the above technique. If you create a link to http://yoursite.com/controller/function/a then a will be passed to function. Same way can have another link b. Do u mean to pass using ajax?

Comment: actually I dont want to pass my details in the parameter, that is the thing..
and no ajax will dispaly the content in the same page but i have to call another view from the controller